Axios in NextJs client and server best practice
I'm new to NextJS and i need a best practice.
I give you an explanation then tell you about my problem.
Explanation
I want to use Axios with interceptors that works for both client and server.
I should mention that I already have a NodeJs backend server.
what I'm trying to do is before make any server or client request I have to call getDeviceToken API which returns a token (DEVICE_TOKEN) that allow me to call other APIs,
and when user login to the page I need the AUTH_TOKEN which i get from Login api call and set this token in cookies instead of DEVICE_TOKEN to call other APIs. otherwise I will get 401 error.
beside that, I want to use Tanstack-Query and in useQuery I will use axiosInstance to call any APIs.
so basically I get DeviceToken if there is'nt any.
and use AUTH_TOKEN or DEVICE_TOEKN to fill the AUTHENTICATION in headers.
this Axios instance may run on Client or Server.
here is my code:
cookie.ts
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export const getClientCookieByName = (name: string) => {
  return Cookies.get(name);
};

export const getServerCookieByName = async (name: string) => {
  const cookieStore = await cookies();
  const auth = cookieStore.get(name);
  return auth;
};


and axiosIntance.ts
// utils/axiosInstance.js
import axios from "axios";
import { getDeviceToken } from "@/api/getAuthDeviceToken";
import { getClientCookieByName } from "./getCookie";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  timeout: 10000,
});

// Request Interceptor: Attach Authorization header
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  // Server-side: Use cookies

  const authToken = getClientCookieByName("AUTH");
  let deviceToken = getClientCookieByName("DEVICE");



  if (!deviceToken) {
    const result = await getDeviceToken();
    deviceToken = result.data.accessToken;
  }

  const token = authToken || deviceToken; // Extract token from cookies

  if (token) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
  return config;
});

// Response Interceptor: Handle errors
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response, // Return response if successful
  async (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error); // For all other errors
  }
);

export default axiosInstance;


Problem:
because I import "next/headers" in a file that may run on client Next raise an error which is totally fine.
You're importing a component that needs "next/headers". That only works in a Server Component which is not supported in the pages/ directory

so how can I get around this ?
and basically what is the best practice for handling JWT auth tokens plus having tanstack and NextJs all at once ?
